# How to disable alt+tab in IE8 aspx web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am struggling in disable alt+tab in IE8 web browser page. my page is a show modal dialogue.

Comment: You might want to look at some JavaScript to do that for you.  But I would recomend against doing that, as it might annoy your users as you are blocking quick access to other programs that they have running.  Just stop and think about how the need to do that waighs against what your users will view your action as.

Comment: I *highly* doubt it's even possible for a *website* to disable OS commands like that.

Comment: ALT Tab is a user's operative system function. If you wan't to mess with that, you should consider writing a software that can take over the SO. Read "What can you do with Javascript" http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/What_can_you_do_with_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want that kind of control over the operating system you'll need to install local software.

If you don't want to port your whole application to native you can write a native helper app that responds to a custom url scheme and processes it accordingly, like

```
myPopover://title/description
```